# Issue with embeding SWF object with javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, embed, flash

I want to embed SWF object to my HTMl file dynamically. So I'm using embedSWF function. It works in chrome browser but it **doesn't work in IE**. (Now I'm testing on IE11 but it must work on IE8)

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9", "expressInstall.swf", "", "", "" ,console.log("flash object is created"));   
</script>
```

here is my html:

```
<div id="myContent"></div>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `console.log()` as callback function, which is wrong. While I don't believe it really matters for swfobject, you can try:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "myContent", "300", "120", "9", "expressInstall.swf", "", "", "" , swfCallback);

function swfCallback( event ) {
    // Will append true/false to your log.
    console.log("flash object is created:", event.success );
}   
</script>
```

To check if there could be issues with IE's Flash Player itself, you could try to log it's version beforehand:

```
console.log( swfobject.getFlashPlayerVersion() );
```

Comment: I changed code as you suggested. This was logged:
flash object is created: false; 
{major: 0, minor: 0, release: 0}

Comment: probably problem is flash player version. I don't know why is it 0, I checked in IE options and "shockwave flash object" is enabled

Comment: Since IE's player is different from Chrome's or whatever I'd suggest explicitly reinstalling it: go to https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/, Choose your OS and "Flash player for Internet Explorer" as a second option.